# Mouse middle button click functionality in Infragistics Ultragrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, infragistics, user-experience

In Excel, middle mouse button click work as a toggle. That is, if you press it once, it will allow you to scroll in your chosen direction till the time you click it again. 
However, in Infragistics Ultragrid, this scrolling functionality is available only while middle mouse button remains pressed. How can I make Infragistics Ultragrid middle mouse button click work as in excel?

Otherwise also, what is the way to do it in winforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not as complicated as you might think. Clicking either the mouse wheel or middle button (depending on the type of Mouse the user has) fires off a [MouseWheel event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousewheel%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) which must be handled and processed like any other event.

You'll need to configure a small "scrolling state machine" for you application. By this, I mean that the user is either scrolling in, say, a `NormalMode`, where using scroll bars or flicking up/down on the mouse wheel produces the same effect (scrolling up/down). Or, the application is in a `HoverScrollingMode` which occurs whenever the user has clicked the middle button (or mouse wheel) and is moving the mouse north or south of the click point.

I can't give you a programming example without seeing how your application currently handles other types of mouse events, but your overall strategy is to handle these `MouseWheel` events, use them to switch your application state (into, say, `HoverScrollingMode`) and then programmatically move the viewport up/down depending on the current position of their mouse.

Hope this helps, and good luck!